# Реализовать обращение к функции PHP из другого файла

Tags: php, функции

Можно как-то реализовать обращение к функции PHP в другом файле?

Есть основной файл РНР - index.php;
Есть функция **function first()** находящаяся в файле - Funct.php;

Можно ли вызвать функцию **first()** в файле *index.php* ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно:

```
require_once('Funct.php');
first();
```

`include_once`, если возможно продолжение работы даже в случае, когда файл отсутствует, но в таком случае получите ошибку:

> Call to undefined function first()

`include`, `require`, чтобы можно было подключить более одного раза. На втором подключиении получите:

> Cannot redeclare first()